# What is the maximum number of view controllers in UITabBarController for tvOS

Tags: uitabbar, tvos

What is the maximum number of view controllers in UITabBarController for tvOS? It's not documented on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).

The screen is obviously bigger than iOS devices. I know for iOS it will add a "More" button if the number is bigger than 5.

> The More Navigation Controller The tab bar has limited space for
> displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view
> controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays
> only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar.
> Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the
> remaining items. The interface for the standard More item includes an
> Edit button that allows the user to reconfigure the tab bar. By
> default, the user is allowed to rearrange all items on the tab bar. If
> you do not want the user to modify some items, though, you can remove
> the appropriate view controllers from the array in the
> customizableViewControllers property.

### Note

> Tab bar customization and
> the More interface is not available in tvOS

## Differences in tvOS

> Tab bar controllers serve the same purpose in tvOS as in iOS, but
> provide slightly different user interface features: The tab bar
> interface appears at the top of the window. When focus leaves the tab
> bar, the tab bar is hidden. Swiping up on the remote shows the tab bar
> again and focuses it. A user can also show and focus the tab bar by
> pressing the Menu button. Swiping down from the tab bar moves focus
> into the content view; specifically, to the first focusable view that
> is visually below the selected tab. Swiping down behaves like a normal
> focus-changing gesture—that is, focus moves in the direction the user
> swiped. If nothing is focusable immediately below the selected tab,
> the closest focusable view is focused instead. Pressing the Select
> button while a tab is focused moves focus into the content view.
> Because there is no direction associated with this change, focus moves
> to the view specified in the content view's preferredFocusedView
> property. Tab bar controllers in tvOS do not support customization. A
> tab bar controller displays only the number of view controllers from
> its viewControllers array that fit on the screen, and does not provide
> the More interface seen in iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it by adding ViewControllers in StoryBoard. No matter how smaller your buttons are, the answer is 7. It will hide if it's more than **7** ViewController. And no "More" button of course. I added an **8** view controller but it only shows **7 (seven)**.

## The answer is 7

Great, right?!

## Solution

Sadly, I wrote my own TabBarController **:(**
**Which is not a subclass of UITabBarController but UIViewController**. Hoping Apple will change this (they'll not.). Should be depending on the size of the buttons, and could auto calculate each specific case.

Best.

Comment: I can confirm this is still a thing with tvOS 13. Just added an eighth `UIViewController` and it never show. I'll probably have to write my own TabBar or come up with another solution!

Comment: Thank you for informing about tvOS 13 @sebleclerc

Comment: Have you had any chance to bypass this limitation? Not sure the best solution...

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't bypass the limitation. It's someone else's class. We can't till they want us to change that. Best.

Comment: That's what I thought... but had to ask. Thanks :)